# Error with adding dependencies in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I ran into such a problem that when adding the get: dependency to flutter, nothing happens. And when importing

```
import 'pack:get/get.dart';
```

to the main file, the editor suggests adding this dependency, but the error "`Cannot read property`" pops up 'replace' of undefined".

Someone may have encountered a similar problem, how to fix it?

```yaml
    name: flutter_application_1
    description: A new Flutter project.
    
    
    publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
    
    
    version: 1.0.0+1
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
    
    
    dependency_overrides:
      flutter_web:
        git:
          url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
          path: packages/flutter_web
      flutter_web_ui:
        git:
          url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
          path: packages/flutter_web_ui
    dependencies:
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    
    dev_dependencies:
    
      
      flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
    
    
    flutter:
    
    
      uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Can you show your pubspec.yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

I guess it is because I have two version on my MacOS system, one is 1.60 and the other is 1.62, and when ver1.62 upgrade to 1.63 this issue happened.

Fix:

Uninstall both version and install ver1.60 ( https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60), the issue gone, then upgrade ver1.60 to ver1.63, and it gone too...

Comment: I solved this problem by simply creating a new project and installing the necessary dependencies in it, and moved my code there)